# Exporting a Blender file for use in SFM doesn't work

Tags: export

So I've installed this blender plugin that allows you to export .blend files to .smd files, called Blender Source Tools. However, I am encountering an issue when I click export. I get this error code:

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_valvesource\export_smd.py", line 207, in execute
self.exportId(context, id)

File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_valvesource\export_smd.py", line 351, in exportId
bake = self.bakeObj(ob)

File "C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_valvesource\export_smd.py", line 930, in bakeObj
ops.uv.smart_project()

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in **call**
ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)

RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.uv.smart_project.poll() failed, context is incorrect

location: (unknown location) :-1

I feel it's an issue with materials, but I have no idea what code means, so it would be a real help if someone were to decode the problem.

[image: Here are my export settings:]

Comment: Hello :). It would be probably good to ask the developers of the addon first.

Comment: Ah, true. Thanks!